# Programming for HbbTV

Tags: html

Anyone here used to develop web tv / hbbtv related apps? For example

http://itv.ard.de/ardepg/index.php

Is there any web related that I can learn about hbbtv programming. Thanks in advance. ;)

*Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the HbbTV specification here:
http://www.hbbtv.org/pages/about_hbbtv/specification.php

BBC has released a framework which supports HbbTV and other SmartTV plattforms:
http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/index.html

Opera provides an VM with an TV emulator on http://dev.opera.com/tv and there is a list of real worls HbbTV apps on http://www.hbbig.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little emulator

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/firehbbtv/

> FireHbbTV integrates with Firefox to help you develop HbbTV
>   (http://www.hbbtv.org/) compliant applications. You can then benefit
>   of strong development tools associated with your favourite browser.
>   Most commonly used HbbTV API are injected on-the-fly on the web page
>   once you activate the plugin support for a given site. Moreover,
>   FireHbbTv provides you with usefull tools such as resize, aspect-ratio
>   switch, safe-area margin display and keyboard navigation miming TV
>   remote control capabilities.
>
> More detailed features list:
>
> ```
> Javascript HbbTV API injected on-the-fly
> Most HbbTV specific <object> support
> Support of HbbTV specific mime-types
> Minimal support of DVB uri
> Smart resize
> Aspect-Ratio switching
> Safe-area margin display
> TV image replacement
> Channel list
> DSM-CC Stream Event simulation
> Keyboard navigation simulating TV Remote control
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to learn HbbTV is looking at existing applications and then looking up unknown findings in the specs. Also have a look at the code of an HbbTV-Testsuite like the free [MIT-xperts HbbTV-Testsuite](https://github.com/mitxp/HbbTV-Testsuite).

Best source of official information for lookup is the official ETSI specification ETSI TS 102 809 as well as the Documents from the Open IPTV Forum.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there aren't any good resources out there at the moment. More resources should appear as time goes on. Your best bet is probably to look at the code of existing applications. There's a set of test applications here;
http://itv.mit-xperts.com/mitxpgo/

And a useful plugin for firefox that provides some HbbTV APIs is here;
http://tum-iptv.aw.atosorigin.com/firehbbtv/index.php

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should go for Opera. As it provides a fully functional HbbTV browser with SDK to play around and an emulator to test your app without using any other device.